# Input string was not in a correct format error not getting resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the `String` value in a list but getting error as

> Input string was not in a correct format.

There are many helpful links available on the net but didn't resolved mine one.

Here is my code.

```
newRow["EXP_TYPE_ID"] = Convert.ToString(e.Record["EXP_TYPE"]);
    newRow["EXP_TYPE"] = CF.ExecuteScaler("Select Type_desc from type_mst where Type_Code = 'PAR' and Type_Abbr ='" + Convert.ToString(e.Record["EXP_TYPE"]) + "'").ToString();
```

and `CF.ExecuteScaler`

```
public string ExecuteScaler(string StrQuery)
{
    DB.EConnection();
    cmd = new OracleCommand(StrQuery, DB.conn);
    cmd.Connection = DB.conn;
    int val=Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    DB.conn.Close();
    string ret = val.ToString();
    return ret;
}
```

**Note** I can't change Scaler function.

**update**

`StrQuery = Select Type_desc from type_mst where Type_Code = 'PAR' and Type_Abbr ='PUR'`

and the value of the query

**PURCHASER**

Comment: Could you please show us the value of `StrQuery` when you pass it to `ExecuteScaler()`?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: @MegaTron: Updated the question with more details

Comment: @sachin: I get error at while executing my query.

Comment: what type is `Type_desc` from the query? if it's string, what are the possible values? it looks like it's not convertible to `int` and that's why it's throwing the exception

Comment: @slawekwin: it is `VARCHAR2 (200 Byte)`  and its value is `PURCHASER` let me know how to convert it . **UPDATE** yes it is string value

Comment: Purchaser is not an int value. Not really clear how you expect code to succeed when it tries to convert to int...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: yup that is the main cause. How to do then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the exception is thrown in the following line?

```
int val=Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

As you have said, `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` returns value `"PURCHASER"`, which then you are trying to convert into `int`. That is clearly not possible, and this is what the exception is saying.

Please try it like that:

```
public string ExecuteScaler(string StrQuery)
{
    DB.EConnection();
    cmd = new OracleCommand(StrQuery, DB.conn);
    cmd.Connection = DB.conn;
    string ret = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    DB.conn.Close();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: getting error as `cannot implicitly convert type int to string` at line `Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: @nad But you said before: Note I can't change Scaler function.

Comment: @MegaTron: I added one more function and renamed it. I said,I cant change the function, but I can add function